# .npmrc config file not reading environment variable to download private Node module

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

When I hardcode my auth token into my .npmrc file, the private module installs as expected.

When I replace the hardcoded token with an environment variable, the private module fails to install.

I've tried multiple ways of writing the variable name, as well as the syntax of the variable in the .npmrc file, due to the following resources:

- [`npm-config` docs on env vars](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#environment-variables)
- [a counter answer to the npm config docs above about the .npmrc variable syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48728994/2145103)
- [npm blog post re: private modules that many folks link to as the source of truth on the matter](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules)

Example .npmrc files:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN
```

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=${npm_token}
```

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=$npm_token
```

And, example .env files, both with and without strings around the value:

```
npm_config_npm_token=ABC123
```

```
npm_token=ABC123
```

```
NPM_CONFIG_NPM_TOKEN=ABC123
```

```
NPM_TOKEN=ABC123
```

**Nothing has worked.**

Any clues?

***EDIT***

I'm using npm v6.9.0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out the error in my assumption, and have come to a solution.

**tl;dr** - create shell-based persistant environment variables, and use the curly braces variable syntax in a .npmrc file.

The error was assuming npm reads project .env files. Apparently npm does not read .env files located in the a project root.

I wanted npm to read from a .env file so that I could keep all relevant data for a project *contained within the project*.

Instead, I created a shell-based environment variable that is always available. The following code blocks show how to add environment variables to your (oh-my-zsh) shell, even if you git watch and publish your dot files.

```
# ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/env.zsh
# be sure this file is gitignored!

export TOKEN="ABC123"
```

```
# ~/.zshrc

source $ZSH/custom/env.zsh
```

```
# example .npmrc

@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=${TOKEN}
```

Thanks to [this npm forum answer](https://npm.community/t/npmrc-does-not-recognize-environment-variables/6666/2?u=brianzelip) that nudged me towards this shell-based solution.

---

ps - because the native OS X `man` pages file `export` and `source` under the `builtin` category, and don't actually provide any details on how each command works, here are links the man page for each:

- [export](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html)
- [source (or dot operator)](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html)

Comment: Nice. It works on my Windows machine. Will this work for Linux and MacOS too?

Comment: @Yamo93 Yes it will work on Linux machine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using macOS, try using the source command in the terminal to refresh the env file.

```
source .env
```

I had the same problem and looked and the same posts you did but none worked until I tried that. I got the hint from [here](http://getpiggybank.com/blog/npm-private-modules-with-heroku/). I also used curly brackets around my variable in the .npmrc file unlike suggested in the posts you linked. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input John. I was able to figure out a solution using persistent shell-based env variables. And like you, I came to realize that stack overflow answer that suggests the npm docs are wrong wrt variable syntax, is actually wrong :) (i.e.: the npm docs are correct).