# Using Azure Devops artifactory npm token from environment variable

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I am looking for a way to remove the need to write the Azure DevOps npm artifactory npm token to a file. In the docs they provide for non Windows environment, they say we should add this content to our `.npmrc`.

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<registry>/npm/registry/

always-auth=true

; begin auth token
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<registry>/npm/registry/:username=<org>
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<registry>/npm/registry/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<registry>/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<registry>/npm/:username=<org>
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<registry>/npm/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<registry>/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

However, I would like to use environment variables for this if it's possible somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The format of these code is fixed. You could to set your PAT(Personal access token) in the environment variables.

Please add the environment variable to your `.bashrc` or other startup shell file.

```
export TOKEN=your PAT
```

Then use it in `.npmrc` file with `${TOKEN}`.

```
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<registry>/npm/registry/:_password=${TOKEN}
```

Similar issues here:

[.npmrc config file not reading environment variable to download private Node module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514076/npmrc-config-file-not-reading-environment-variable-to-download-private-node-mod)

[How to set env var for .npmrc use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728714/how-to-set-env-var-for-npmrc-use)