# Personal Access Tokens for install Github npm packages

Tags: github, github-package-registry

I managed to publish a simple test package on the Github packageregistry using this tutorial : https://docs.github.com/en/packages/quickstart

Now, if I understand correctly, to use it in a project I have to create a .npmrc file with the following lines :

```
@OWNER:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=PAT
```

1- If somebody else wants to install my public package, do I need to provide them my own PAT ? Or can you install any Github public package with your own PAT ?

2- How can I hide my PAT from the .npmrc file ? I tried to setup a TOKEN variable in my .env file (located in the same directory as the .npmrc file) and calling it with ${TOKEN}, but it doesn't seem to work (authentication fails when running npm install, while inserting the same PAT directly in the file it works).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Any PAT with the `read:packages` scope can read public packages. You don't need to provide your own PAT to anyone. See [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-permissions-for-github-packages#about-scopes-and-permissions-for-package-registries) for details.

2: npm doesn't read from local .env files. You need to export the PAT as an environment variable (`export TOKEN="ABC123"`). Then you can use it with `${TOKEN}` when calling the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll have to export your PAT from your local machine's shell since .npmrc does not read the .env file.
Please see the following thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55578270/6026781

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.